# Desktop App Converter does not capture regitryes under HKCU

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have a MSI file which adds some entries under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software hive. It seems that the App Converter totally ignores them. Tee registries under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE are detected ok.

Has anyone encountered this issue? Maybe a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of the Desktop App Converter are you using? 
Based on this article (https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/07/14/choosing-the-path-forward-for-existing-desktop-apps-4/#XQ357VMxKTV1btdX.97), the Desktop App Converter can capture registry under HKCU. 
Do you meet any error when you try to detect the registry under HKCU?

Comment: BTW: If you have any feedback about Desktop App Converter, please post it on UserVoice site(https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/category/161895-desktop-bridge-centennial), Centennial team is currently monitor feedback on the UserVoice site.

Comment: I have version 0.1.25 for anniversary update.

Comment: @Ciprian Thanks for reporting this issue, could you please tell us which tool you are using to create an MSI installation package? WIX?Advanced Installer?

Comment: I used AvancedInstaller, but it was nothing fancy. Just a new key and value under HKCU\Software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a MSI file which adds some entries under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software hive. It seems that the App Converter totally ignores them

During deployment, we only support keys in the package under HKLM\Software. At runtime the application can write to HKCU but package content is per-machine only. That the reason you will find they are all ignored under HKCU\Software.

Let's clarify something may misunderstand:

**Deployment:**

Centennial packages may include private package registry data. **This data must logically sit under HKLM\Software**. No other registry locations are supported. When the package is deployed, this registry data is made available to the application.

**Runtime:**

Once an application is launched and running it can read or enumerate its package registry data under HKLM\Software. The running application may also read or write to HKCU.